# Correct way to postpone messages in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using akka cluster in order to perform distributed computations in two pahses. First `phaseA` then `phaseB`. To handle phases I use akka's FSM.

There is no hard synchronization so one of the nodes may reach `phaseB` while others are still in `phaseA`.

The problem is, one in `phaseB` sends `phaseB-related` messages to others (they are in `phaseA` yet) what causes them to loose `phaseB-related` messages.

For now I use simple trick to postpone unknown messages:

```
case any => self ! any
```

But IMO this is not proper way to do that. I know I can also schedule `any` using akka scheduler, but I don't like this either.

Here is simplified code:

```
package whatever

import akka.actor._

object Test extends App {

  case object PhaseA
  case object PhaseB

  class Any extends Actor {

    def phaseA: Receive = {
      case PhaseA => {
        context.become(phaseB)
        println("in phaseB now")
      }
      case any => self ! any
    }

    def phaseB: Receive = {
      case PhaseB => println("got phaseB message !")
    }

    def receive = phaseA

  }

  val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
  val any = system.actorOf(Props(new Any), name = "any")
  any ! PhaseB
  any ! PhaseA
}
```

What is the correct way to postpone messages in such a situation?

Comment: Have the actor in phase A put the messages into a queue and then send them to itself when it enters phase B. Reason about actors as if they were people. What would you do if someone hands you a message on a piece of paper that you aren't ready to handle yet? Put in on pile on your desk until you're ready to deal with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can stash messages for later processing.  Mix `akka.actor.Stash` into your actors and `stash()` your `phaseB` messages for later.

When your FSM is in `phaseA` and receives a `phaseB` message, call `stash()`.  When that actor then transitions into the `phaseB` state, call `unstashAll()` and all the stashed messages will be redelivered.