# Is there a name for this asyncronous actor initialization idiom?

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, initialization, akka, actor

Whenever I create an actor that needs some asynchronously obtained data to initialize itself, I find myself using an idiom like this. Does it have a name? (And is it the best way to do it?)

```scala
class AsyncInitActor(db: Database, someId: UUID) extends Actor with ActorStash {
    case class Initialize(something: Something)

    override def preStart() = {
        db.getSomething(someId) onSuccess { something =>
            self ! Initialize(something)
        }
    }

    def receive = {
        case Initialize(something) =>
            context become initialized(something)
            unstashAll()

        case _ => stash()
    }

    def initialized(something): Receive = {
        case whatever =>
    }
}
```

In the case of actors created by cluster sharding, the asynchronous request happens in `receive` instead of `preStart`.

**To be clear, I am not looking for a GoF pattern.**

Answer (score 1):

I have never used stash for this.  If I really need to initialize, I'm more likely to use FSM to ensure that my actor is in a ready state.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fsm.html

I suppose you could combine both approaches.

Comment: Can you give an example? What do you do with messages that arrive in your start state if you're not stashing them?

Comment: I think stash is there exactly for that purpose.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005231/correct-way-to-postpone-messages-in-akka

Of course you could also store in the actor state.  Frankly I would normally use FSM to reject other messages before the behavior has been changed with 'become' to some READY state.  I haven't much needed to accept messages prior to the actor being ready. 
https://github.com/SalmaKhater/Learning-Akka/blob/master/hotswap-behavior/src/main/scala/FSM.scala is another example.

Answer (score 0):

The closest design pattern that comes to my mind is Proxy.

Per the documentation [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy):

> Design a surrogate, or proxy, object that: instantiates the real object the first time the client makes a request of the proxy, remembers the identity of this real object, and forwards the instigating request to this real object. Then all subsequent requests are simply forwarded directly to the encapsulated real object.

In your case, you can think of the actor being wrapped by a proxy. Once the actor is initialized from database, the proxy forwards all requests to it, i.e. the *real* actor. Until then, the proxy returns null, *default* actor or something.

Comment: No, it's not a proxy. The actor isn't forwarding requests to another actor, it's just delaying the ones it handles itself until after initialization.

Comment: You *can* design it this way that wrapper waits for initialization and forwards correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I ***create*** an actor that ***needs*** some asynchronously obtained
>   data to ***initialize*** itself...

I would say, you basically described a Factory pattern. And if your actors are DDD concepts then it would be in the context of DDD Repository. In other words, you are dealing with a complex creation of an entity along with its validation - the ***need*** part. One of the responsibilities of a DDD repository is to yield a ***valid*** aggregate root.

My two cents.

Sergiy

<><

Comment: No, it's not the Factory pattern. I'm looking for a name for this specifically asynchronous pattern. Maybe it would be better called an idiom.

Comment: I am not quite clear of your intent here. Asynchronycity of the operation does not change the intention. Intention defines the pattern. Patterns by definition solve reoccurring problem. The fact that you change it to idiom does not remove the essence of it. It is in your case a multistep creation of a valid actor.

Comment: My intent is to find out whether this specific idiom of *asynchronous* initialization of an actor has a name. Calling a Factory does not convey that that is what is happening.